# Image upload JS (Max Uploads)

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
          
          // Old code here
          /*$("<img></img>", {
            class: "imageThumb",
            src: e.target.result,
            title: file.name + " | Click to remove"
          }).insertAfter("#files").click(function(){$(this).remove();});*/
          
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

And i need a upload limit of 3 images, And also error codes like bad words

I tried every code and add it in between it doesnt seem to work or break the code

Comment: More context pls

Comment: In this code above i need a limit maxium of 3 files you can upload and not more then 3

Comment: [Code samples](/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article, and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Comment: Questions should be about a [single, specific programming problem](/help/on-topic), and should explain the expected/desired results/behaviors, along with the actual.

Answer (score 1):

For Multiple Selection, In **file chooser dialog box press ctrl button** and select multiple files.

**Here you can try this logic :**

```js
function fileCheck(ev) {
        let files = ev.target.files;
        if (files.length > 3) {
          alert("max upload is 3");
          ev.target.value = "";
          // if form then you can use form.reset()
          return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          let file = new FileReader();
          file.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

          file.onloadend = (ev2) => {
            document.body.innerHTML += `
        <img src=${ev2.currentTarget.result} width="200" height="200">
        `;
          };
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" multiple onchange="fileCheck(event)" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do insert your code into mine above?

Comment: After this line in your code -> var files = e.target.files. my code can be inserted.

Comment: In Jquery $ -> document(in JS)

Comment: When I insert it it gives the alert max upload is 3 and when i press okay it still returns all the selected images and that are more then 3

Comment: https://paste.ee/r/85tuL

Comment: please check i have updated my answer.

Comment: Now nothing works preview or alert

Comment: ok i am sending live url link

Comment: please check the code. only js file to see implementation.

Comment: let me check it out was away sorry

Comment: it dint work it wont upload any image / it wont show the preview

Comment: this is what you made https://codepen.io/MrDanielNL/pen/YzjwQRd

Comment: this is what it is before your code is added https://codepen.io/vineshsingh90/pen/yzBVXj

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: Now please check the updated url :https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-id1ewb?file=index.html

Comment: Now it will work good. please check.

Comment: updated URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-id1ewb?file=index.html

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Selection, In **file chooser dialog box press ctrl button** and select multiple files.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="file" id="files" multiple />
    <script>
      $(document).ready(() => {
        $('#files').change(function (ev) {
          let files = ev.target.files;
          if (files.length > 3) {
            alert('max upload is 3');
            ev.target.value = '';
            // if form then you can use form.reset()
            return;
          }

          for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = new FileReader();
            file.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

            file.onloadend = (ev2) => {
              document.body.innerHTML += `
        <img src=${ev2.currentTarget.result} width="200" height="200">
        `;
            };
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check is this working?

Comment: Its not working please insert it into the javascript not into the index Thanks for helping me buddy :) https://codepen.io/vineshsingh90/pen/yzBVXj

Comment: please tell me what is error now and index means ?

Comment: When i put it in the index form and not in js, it wont show the preview etc you removed the code for the preview etc

Comment: but It is previewing image in my system. i have not removed the code for preview.

Comment: https://codepen.io/MrDanielNL/pen/YzjwQRd < Wont remove or add other images then 1

Comment: remove your code because your previous code is overriding my code.

Comment: only use my code.

Comment: only use my code and remove your code completely from JS file as it in this link : https://codepen.io/MrDanielNL/pen/YzjwQRd

Comment: I did that then it doesnt have the remove option etc https://codepen.io/MrDanielNL/pen/YzjwQRd

Comment: you can run this file locally in your system.

Comment: The html wont work got any ideas left for the js part? since that almost worked?

Comment: This works fine with the javascript part https://codepen.io/MrDanielNL/pen/YzjwQRd only need it limit to 3 uploads thats all